# Get value from INPUT inside GridView

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, .net, html

I have a GridView with a non ASP object (INPUT type for suggestions) and i want to get the values from those forms to the code behind, how do I do it?

```
<ItemTemplate>
    <tr style="background-color: #E0FFFF; color: #333333;">
        <td style="text-align: left;padding-left:10px">
            <asp:Label ID="DESLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("DES") %>' />
        </td>
        <td style="text-align: left">
            <input id ="PROD" style="width:100%;Height:25px" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:Label ID="PRODQUANTLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("PRODQUANT") %>' />
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:TextBox ID="AVQUANTLabel" runat="server" Height="25px" Width="65px" Text='<%# Eval("AVQUANT") %>' />
        </td>
    </tr>
</ItemTemplate>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can user findcontrol meyhod

in for loop or in RowUpdating Event

1.firt way in Loop, 2 RowUpdating Methid

```
 foreach (GridDataItem item in RadGrid1.Items)
    {
        string id = item["ID"].Text;
        string firstName = (item["TempColumn1"].FindControl("PRODQUANTLabel") as Lable).Text;
    }

protected void GridView1_RowUpdating(object sender,idViewUpdateEventArgs e)
  {
              GridView gv = (GridView)sender;
              GridViewRow gvRow = gv.Rows[e.RowIndex];
              Lable tb = (Lable) gridview1.FindControl("PRODQUANTLabel");
              if (tb == null)
                 throw new ApplicationException("Could not find Lable");

              string strValue= tb.Text;

   }
```

Comment: It's the input data I need, not the Label, the asp controls are working fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the value on code behind as any simple form post. To do that you first make sure that you have a `name` field on your input control.

```
<input id ="PROD" name="prod" style="width:100%;Height:25px" />
```

then on post back you can get the value using the [`Request.Form`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httprequest.form?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2)

```
var value = Request.Form["prod"]
```

Comment: Don't forget it's inside a listview wich means there is more than one with the same name and ID

Comment: @JoãoPedroSousa You need to handle that, either separate after the post back, either add extra numbers on the id (like prod.1, prod.2 etc)

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using another method using asp texboxes. Still working on in.